JSON path to test the value of a key
I want to test the value of a json object using jsonpath.
What should have been straightforward, doesn't seem to be. Here is the object:
{
  "test_type": {
    "id": "myId",
    "name": "My Name"
  }
}

And the JSONPath:
$.test_type[?(@.id == 'myId')]

Both in my app(nodejs/angular) and jsonpath.com, this is returning no matches.
However, if I just use ..[?(@.id=='myId')], matching is happening correctly.
Is the JSON path I'm trying with incorrect?

What you have should work fine.  Please test it on my online evaluator, https://json-everything.net/json-path.

The implementation your using may not support underscore in shorthand names.
It may not support spaces in the filter expression.

Try $['test_name'][?(@.id=='myId')].

Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work there as well. I tried with both $['test_type'][?(@.id=='myId')] and $.test_type[?(@.id=='myId')]

The issue is that the JSONPath query $.test_type[?(@.id == 'myId')]
assumes test_type is an array, but in your JSON, test_type is an object, not an array. That is why the query returns nothing.

If test_type is an object, you can directly query for the id value using $.test_type.id and compare it in your code.
If you want the query $.test_type[?(@.id == 'myId')] to work, please change your current json to:
{"test_type": [{"id": "myId","name": "My Name"}]}

